# Twitter Typeahead case insensitive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, typeahead.js

I am using Twitters typeahead (http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js)

It is working fine except that hes filtering case senstive and i want the filter to be case insensitive.

How do i implement that?

this is my code:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    name: 'Title',
    remote: base_url + '/Activity/Components/Phrase/Home/SearchCharacter?q=%QUERY',
    valueKey: 'Title',
    limit: 10 
}).bind('typeahead:selected', function (obj, char) {
    $(this).attr('data-charid', char.ID);
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have your code running in `/Activity/Components/Phrase/Home/SearchCharacter` do a case-insensitive search.