# How to make a JSON array case insensitive for Twitter Typeahead?

Tags: php, arrays, json, postgresql, typeahead.js

I am using the [Twitter Typeahead library](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) to retrieve address results as the user types a query, but am noticing an issue with the case sensitivity.

The address data is held on a Postgres database and I am using PHP to query the table in the database with the string the user types, and then push the fields into an array which is then encoded to JSON.

This works fine and returns results, but only if the user enters the correct case (I want them to be able to enter any case and it return results).

Is this something I need to alter in my typeahead / bloodhound functions, or do I need to do something additional to my JSON array so it is made case insensitive?

My php script is below if that helps.

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['query'])) {
    // Connect to our database
    $conn = pg_connect("host=myhost port=myport dbname=mydb user=myuser password=mypass");

    // Retrieve the query
    $query = $_GET['query'];

    // Search the database for all similar items
    $sql = pg_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM addresses.llpg_basic WHERE full_address LIKE '%{$query}%'");
    $array = array();

    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $address = array(
        'ADDRESS' => $row['full_address'],
        'POSTCODE' => $row['postcode'],
        'UPRN' => $row['uprn'],
        'X' => $row['xref'],
        'Y' => $row['yref']
        );
        array_push($array, $address);
    }

    sort($array);

    $jsonstring = json_encode($array);

    // Return the json array
    echo $jsonstring;
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you want perform a case insensitive **postgresql query?** See [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/381C37A3.EC9D5D4D@tm.ee)

Comment: No I want to perform a case insensitive twitter typeahead search - but the typeahead seems to only search the addresses case sensitively.

Comment: In your code there are only db code: why, if it is not relevat for your question? BTW, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946825/twitter-typeahead-case-insensitive?rq=1)

Comment: Because I thought it might be a problem with using a Postgres table (I also have a typeahead working that takes data from a MSSQL table and this works ok with case insensitive data, which is making me think it might be some kind of problem with Postgres and PHP?)

Comment: @Chris - MSSQL's `WHERE` is case insensitive by default, postgresql's is not - thats why your "MSSQL typeahead" is working, so see fusion3k's first comment.

Comment: Ah ok yes sorry @davidkonrad I do want to do a case insensitive postgres query then! :) 
I tried using lower(myfield) but this now only works if the user types lower case, is there a function to allow any case?

Comment: Use `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE` in the SQL query